# property inheritance without valuing joint

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties

I want to inherit some properties that are the same in 2 classes using interface or abstract class; I don't want to declare variable in child classes.

Is it possible to do this?

**Parent Class:**

```
interface IError
{
    DateTime GETDATE { get; set; }
    string ERROR_NUMBER { get; set; }
    string ERROR_SEVERITY { get; set; }
    string ERROR_STATE { get; set; }
    string ERROR_PROCEDURE { get; set; }
    string ERROR_LINE { get; set; }
    string ERROR_MESSAGE { get; set; }
}
```

**Child :**

```
public class Business
{
    public Business()
    {
        this.Id = -1;
        this.Message = "";
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

**Another child:**

```
public class DbTools
{
  //Another Class

}
```

I need parent properties in this two classes, but if change code like below, I should use another variable that I don't want to:

```
public class Business : IError
{
    private DateTime m_GetDATE;//I don't want to declare another variable
    public DateTime GETDATE
    {
        get { return m_GetDATE; }
        set { GETDATE = m_GetDATE; }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking.  Perhaps a code mock up of your idea of what you dont want to do and more explaining what you do want to do.

Comment: @paqogomez , I change my code , take it out off on hold.

Comment: I've voted to reopen.  Its got 3 votes so far and will likely find the others.  As for your problem.  You arent doing anything special with `m_GetDATE`  Why not just use an [auto-implemented property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx#Y12300)  like `public DateTime GETDATE{get;set;} public string ERROR_NUMBER{get;set;}` ?  You could do this with all your properties and not need any backing fields.

Comment: I don't want to repeat this properties in two child, I want to declare these in a parent class and just inheritance two child classes from parent.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want a base class `public class ErrorBase: IError` that implements all the properties.  Then your child classes, `public class Business: ErrorBase` and `public class DbTools:ErrorBase` inherit from it and will get all the implemented properties automatically.

Comment: yes, but how to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want an `abstract` base class:

```
public abstract class ErrorBase : IError
{
     public DateTime GETDATE { get; set; }
     //...ditto all the other IError properties
}
```

Then you can just inherit that:

```
public class Business : ErrorBase
{
    // all the ErrorBase properties are inherited
}
```

You could also make the base class properties `virtual` just in case you need to `override` them in the derived classes at any point.

The other thing you might consider is composing rather than inheriting. It doesn't seem all that natural that `Business` and `DbTools` should be inheriting from the same base class, so instead have a (non-abstract) `ErrorBase` class that implements `IError` and have `Business` and `DbTools` have an `Error` property:

```
public class ErrorBase : IError
{
     public DateTime GETDATE { get; set; }
     //...ditto all the other IError properties
}

public interface IHaveError
{
    ErrorBase Error { get; set; }
}

public class Business : IHaveError
{
    public ErrorBase { get; set; }
}
```

As a bonus, you could make `IHaveError` actually be `IHaveErrors` and have a `List<ErrorBase>` property allowing your objects to hold more than one error, which might be useful sometimes.

Comment: Great answer, just what I'd envisioned.  love the idea of the error properties too.

Comment: But now it seems OP has deleted his account.  That sucks.